# getting particular column value from one csv and push that column values in other csv in python

Tags: python, csv, pandas

I've a requirement like, acquiring 10th column values from csv1 file and push the same column of values to other csv2 file. [Assume csv1 and csv2 file has same no.of rows].
How to achieve this with simple way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution use [`read_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html) with select by parameter `usecols` column for read:

```
temp=u"""a,b,c
1,4,5
7,8,9
"""
#in real data change 2 to 11 (python counts from 0)
#after testing replace StringIO(temp) to filename
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(temp), usecols=[2])
print (df)
   c
0  5
1  9
```

Read another file:

```
temp=u"""a1,b1,c1
7,8,1
5,3,0
"""
#after testing replace StringIO(temp) to filename
df1 = pd.read_csv(StringIO(temp))
print (df1)
   a1  b1  c1
0   7   8   1
1   5   3   0
```

Replace columns from `df` (there is only one column) to `df1` - select by position by [`iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html):

```
#in real data change 2 to 11    
df1.iloc[:, 2] = df.iloc[:, 0]
print (df1)
   a1  b1  c1
0   7   8   5
1   5   3   9
```

Last write [`to_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html):

```
df1.to_csv('filename.csv', index=False)
a1,b1,c1
7,8,5
5,3,9
```

Comment: Thanks jezrael.
But, I want to add the column values c i.e [5,9] to df1 csv file. So, that it should have 4 columns.

Comment: then use instead `df1.iloc[:, 2] = df.iloc[:, 0]` `df1['col_name'] = df.iloc[:, 0]`

Comment: I ran it, but observed below error.
NameError: name 'StringIO' is not defined.
I'm using python 2.7.10 version

Comment: I run python 3. So you need `import io` and then add `io` - `pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(temp)` for python 2

Comment: Thank you. As I'm reading the external csv file, so it's throwing
"TypeError: initial_value must be unicode or None, not str". To resolve it, I can't disturb the existing csv file by making it unicode(<file>).
How to overcome this issue.... Thanks in-advance

Comment: I've used : `df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO('process_diskActivity.csv'), usecols=[11])`

Comment: It is wrong, use `df = pd.read_csv('process_diskActivity.csv', usecols=[11]) `

Comment: Is something problem with accepting? Please click on the check mark under 0 in left top of my answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in. thank you.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130759/discussion-between-user3655447-and-jezrael).